# PIC18F4550 - How to run a specific function for each character of a string send through TeraTerm?

Tags: pic18

I have a function that I have to run for each character in a string that I receive through TeraTerm. But how can I iterate through every character of the string if I receive all of them together?

Comment: Post function code :)